# How to change the navbar-brand a:hover background-color in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a ruby on rails app with Bootstrap 5. I'm trying to change the background color of the navbar-brand class anchors when hovering. I can change the regular, non-anchor background-color just fine. But why isn't the a:hover background changing?

```
  .navbar-brand {background-color: #0f0; } /* works */
  .navbar-brand a:hover {background-color: #f00;} /* doesn't work */
```

It's probably something very simple. I'm just not seeing it.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the inspector pane in your browser to see if the style pane gives any kind of info `i` on why that rule may be overwritten?

Comment: Have you tried adding a class to your anchor tag, unique class and using it, like `<a class="unique-class">` then `.unique-class:hover`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because the css from Bootstrap has [has more weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

TTry to add `!important`

```
   a.navbar-brand:hover {background-color: #f00 !important;}
```

Comment: !important did not fix it.
It seems that it's not picking up the class on the anchor.  If i simply use a:hover without the actual .navbar-brand class it works (but also changes it for every anchor.)
If I wrap that in a div it works.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work for a non-bootstrap anchor. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQQURTGHXALQ

Comment: `.one:hover { background-color: yellow; }` works in your linked w3schools code as the a tag has a class of `.one`

Comment: it doesn't.  .one is supposed to be yellow.  the style without the class is green.

Comment: It does indeed, check it: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQQV12H0BW2K, make sure you are pressing run first as indicated in code snip

Comment: It's not.  they were both showing green. I've removed the style without the class.  Please try this:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQQV1JASX9IA

Comment: Your code is false @SMHauck. This is what you wrote `.one a:hover` this is what you should've `a.one:hover `

Comment: omg i knew I was doing something stupid.  It's been a long day!  thank you so much!